# CSS3 Animation - Keyframe To For Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, keyframe

I've looked around a bit on how CSS3 does not currently support a `height: auto` value for keyframe animations.

One of the tricks seems to be using `max-height` as a value to sort of hack it to work.

I'm trying to do the opposite. I want my header wrapper to shrink and have the navigation slide up under it where it belongs.

I have a simple mockup ready if somebody could show me any tricks of how to set up `inherit` or `auto` while avoiding javascript.

**CSS3 Playground** (*Static height*)

https://jsfiddle.net/z3ytveu5/3/

```css
@keyframes logoWrapDrop {
  from {
    height: 500px;
  }
  to {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#logoWrap {
  background: #69C;
}
#logoWrap.animating {
  animation-name: logoWrapDrop;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
#navigation li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoWrap" class="animating">
  <h1>Responsive Content - Dynamic Height</h1>
  <p>
    How to avoid static keyframe "to" px?
  </p>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>Nav 1</li>
    <li>Nav 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Am I going to have to use JavaScript/jQuery to achieve this? Or is there a CSS3 only workaround to define the automatic height of my wrapper?

**Working with JS** (*Dynamic height*):

https://jsfiddle.net/z3ytveu5/2/

```js
$(function() {
  var h = $('#logoWrap').height();
  $.keyframe.define({
    name: 'logoWrapDrop',
    from: {
      'height': '500px'
    },
    to: {
      'height': h + 'px'
    }
  });
  $('#logoWrap').addClass('animating');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#logoWrap {
  background: #69C;
}
#logoWrap.animating {
  animation-name: logoWrapDrop;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
#navigation li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquerykeyframes/0.0.9/jquery.keyframes.min.js"></script>
<div id="logoWrap">
  <h1>Responsive Content - Dynamic Height</h1>
  <p>
    How to avoid static keyframe "to" px?
  </p>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>Nav 1</li>
    <li>Nav 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you ok doing something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/z3ytveu5/4/)?

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't try min-height in both fields... I think that'll do, as the inconsistent timing doesn't matter in this scenario as it only moves one way. That should work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use the opposite of `max-height` which is the `min-height`. Initially set `min-height` to some arbitrary large value and then animate it to 0px. Since the `height` is set as `auto`, it will not shrink beyond what is necessary to show the content.

```css
@keyframes logoWrapDrop {
  from {
    min-height: 500px;
  }
  to {
    min-height: 0px;
  }
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#logoWrap {
  background: #69C;
}
#logoWrap.animating {
  animation-name: logoWrapDrop;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
#navigation li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoWrap" class="animating">
  <h1>Responsive Content - Dynamic Height</h1>
  <p>
    How to avoid static keyframe "to" px?
    <br>How to avoid static keyframe "to" px?
    <br>How to avoid static keyframe "to" px?
  </p>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>Nav 1</li>
    <li>Nav 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Snippet with lesser content:**

```css
@keyframes logoWrapDrop {
  from {
    min-height: 500px;
  }
  to {
    min-height: 0px;
  }
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#logoWrap {
  background: #69C;
}
#logoWrap.animating {
  animation-name: logoWrapDrop;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
#navigation li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoWrap" class="animating">
  <h1>Responsive Content - Dynamic Height</h1>
  <p>
    How to avoid static keyframe "to" px?
  </p>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>Nav 1</li>
    <li>Nav 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```